# Cannot read PARSE database value

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, parse-platform, svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js'
    import dayjs from 'dayjs'

    export let showModalThree // boolean
    export let userToChangeId: string = ''

    let user: Parse.User = null
    let dialog // HTMLDialogElement

    let value = ''

    $: if (dialog && showModalThree) dialog.showModal()

    $: if (dialog && showModalThree && userToChangeId) {
        fetchData(userToChangeId);
    }

    async function fetchData(userId) {
        const data = Parse.Object.extend('data');
        const query = new Parse.Query(data);
        query.equalTo('user', userId);
        console.log(userId) // Shows correct userID

        try {
            const theData = await query.first();

            if (theData) {
                value = theData.get('value');
                console.log(theData.get('value'));
            } else {
                console.log('no theData found for this user.');
                console.error('Error: no theData found.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Fout bij het ophalen van gegevens:', error);
        }
    }
</script>
```

But there is a user with the value in the database. If i use:

```
query.equalTo('objectId', variableWithCorrectObjectId);
```

instead of

```
query.equalTo('user', userId);
```

Than i can see the value.
How can i fix this so I can see the correct value when i use the user assigned to the data?

Comment: Is it correct that `console.log(userId)` does not have a `;`?

Comment: @Hille Yes that's not the problem.

Comment: Please write a answer with your solution, otherwise people will think that it's still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the roles of my database that was the problem for me!
And add:

```
let userPointerUser = { __type: 'Pointer', className: '_User', objectId: userId }
query.equalTo('user', userPointerUser)
query.equalTo('type', 'sleep')
```